# Promise, update parent scope variable

Tags: javascript, mongoose, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I have this code:

```
router.put('/test', (ctx, next) => {
  post.create(something, (err, newPost) => {
    if (err) return
    ctx.body = newPost
  })
  console.log(ctx.body) // => undefined
  ctx.status = 200
})
```

The problem is the value I set in the callback to the ctx.body variable is lose outside of the callback.
And I fail to get it works. I tried `bind`/`async await` but without success.
Can you help me ?

EDIT: @CertainPerformance, the "duplicate" [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) you linked does not answer my question because the solution it proposes includes to modify directly the signature of function which produces the promise `post.create` in my case. And I can't simply do that because it is part of Mongoose API. I read the entire post and I didn't found a solution. So what we do with this post?

EDIT: Based on the answer below, I found two solutions:

```
router.put('/test', async (ctx, next) => {
  const newPost = await Post.create(something).then(post => post)
  ctx.body = newPost
  ctx.status = 200
})
```

and

```
router.put('/test', async (ctx, next) => {
  const newPost = new Post(something)
  await newPost.save()
  ctx.body = newPost
  ctx.status = 200
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using async/await for example :

```js
createPromisified(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    post.create(data, (err, ret) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);

      return resolve(ret);
    });
  });
}

router.put('/test', async(ctx, next) => {
  await createPromisified(something);

  ctx.body = newPost;
 
  ctx.status = 200;
})
```

---

Using generic code example which represent your case :

```js
function postCreate(data, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(false, 'ret'), 300);
}

function createPromisified(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    postCreate(data, (err, ret) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);

      return resolve(ret);
    });
  });
}

async function routerPut(ctx, next) {
  await createPromisified('something');

  console.log(ctx.body);

  ctx.body = 'newData';

  console.log(ctx.body);

  ctx.status = 200;
}


routerPut({
    body: 'hey',
  },

  () => {
    console.log('next');
  },
);
```

Comment: Hi, ok this working fine thx, but can you explain me something ? `post.create` return already a Promise. So I tested your code but with removing the `return new Promise` which wraps `post.create`, and I return directly the result of the Promise produces by `post.create` instead. But this does not work. Why ?

Comment: Ok I understand why! It's fine